# Is Big(O) machine dependent?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am really confused with Big(O) notation. Is Big(O) machine dependent or machine independent ? (Machine in the sense the computer in which we run the Algorithm) 
Will Sorting of 1000 numbers using quick sort in i3 processor and i7 processor be the same ? Why don't we consider the machine and it's processor speed when calculating the Time Complexity ? I am a neophyte in this stuff.

Comment: Big O is a mathematical concept about abstract algorithms. How can math be machine-dependent?

Comment: No, it is not.  Big(O) is about how the steps you're taking to solve the problem scale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Big-O is a measure of scalability, not of speed. It shows you what effect on time and memory it has when you e.g. double the amount of data - does it double the execution, or quadruple it?

Whether you use i7 or i3, double is double. Whether a linear algorithm is fast or slow, double is double.

This also has another implication many people ignore. A complex algorithm such as `O(n^3)` can be faster than a simple algorithm such as `O(n)` for a given `n` that is below a certain limit. Example:

```
loop n times:
    loop n times:
        loop n times:
            sleep 1 second
```

is `O(n^3)`, as it has 3 nested loops.

```
loop n times:
    sleep 10 seconds
```

is `O(n)`, as it only has one loop. For `n = 10` the first program executes for 1000 seconds, and the second one executes for only 100. So, `O(n)` is good! one would be tempted to say. But if you have `n = 2`, the first, complex program executes in only 8 seconds, while the second, simpler one executes for 20! Even for `n = 3`, the first executes in 27 seconds, the second one in 30. So while the `n` is low, a complex program might be able to outperform the simpler one. It's just that as `n` rises, the complex program gets slower much faster (if that makes sense) than a simple one. For `n = 1000`, the simple code has risen to only 10000 seconds, but the complex one is now 1000000000 seconds!

Also, this clearly shows you that complexity is not processor-dependent. A second is a second.

EDIT: Also, you might want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o), where Big-O is explained in a number of very high-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Big(O) Notation is the method of calculating the complexity of an algorithm, and hence the relative time it will take to run. The same algorithm, for the same data, will run faster on a faster processor, but will still take the same number of operations. It's used as a way of evaluating the relative efficiency of different algorithms to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation is not architecture-dependent in any way, it is a Mathematical construct.It is a very limited measure of algorithmic complexity, it only gives you a rough upper bound for how performance changes with data size.

Answer (score 0):

Big(O) is alogorithm dependent.   It's job is to help compare the relative costs of various algorithms, without the need to consider the machine dependencies.

Linear search though an array, on average will look at about 1/2 of the elements if it is found.  for all practical purposes that is O(N/2) which is the same as O(1/2 * N).  for compairson, you toss away the coefficient. hence it is O(N) for use.

A binary tree can hold N elements for searching as well.  on agerage it will look though log base 2 (N) to find something, hence you will see it described as cost O(LN2(N)).

pop in small values for N, and there isn't a whole lot of difference between the algorithms.   Pop in a large value of N, and it will be clear that the binary tree lookup is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Big(O) is not machine dependent. It is mathematical notation to denote complexity of an algorithm. Usually we use these notations in theory to compare algorithms performance.